# Manually trigger opening of Google sign-in popup with "Google Identity Services" to get `id_token`

Tags: google-oauth

Is there a programmable way to get the `id_token` with "Google Identity Services" like you could previously with `gapi.auth2.authorize`?
I have a use case where I have a completelly custom google sign-in button and by clicking it, I'm calling `gapi.auth2.authorize` to show the
Google sign-in popup window. After user successfull sign in, I receive the `id_token`. This token is then send to backend server to validate/authenticate the user and to sign him in to my application.
For example:

```
    const config: gapi.auth2.AuthorizeConfig = {
        client_id: <client_id>,
    scope: 'email profile openid',
    prompt: 'consent',
    response_type: 'id_token',
    include_granted_scopes: false
    };
    
    gapi.auth2.authorize(config, (response) => {
        console.log(response.id_token);
        // redirect or send to backend server
    })
```

As far I can see there is now way how to do it with the new "Google Identity Services" API.
As I understand, you use methods under `google.accounts.id` for authentication and under `google.accounts.oauth2` for authorization.
With methods under `google.accounts.id` I can just show the `prompt` (One Tap popup) or call `renderButton` (the rendered button can be customized just to some extent).
And methods under `google.accounts.oauth2` return just "access_token" (e.g. `requestAccessToken`) or "authorization code" (e.g. `requestCode`).

I would have assumed there would be some method like `requestIdToken` (or `requestCredential`) under `google.accounts.id`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, so you're not alone. Hoping someone here has some insight on how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

### How to display login modal window?

From what I understood Google doesn't want you to create your own button and add onClick listener to invoke login modal window.

Instead they want to render the button by themselves.

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton([elementRef or selector], {button config})
```

You can get that config using their [configurator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator).

### How to get the id_token?

Once you have the button rendered you need to "initialise the listener" (do it once its NOT an onClick event)

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
   client_id: [your_client_id],
   callback: (authResponse) => {
     const token = authResponse.credentials <-- I believe this is an id_token now
   }
```

Now you just click the button rendered by Google, it should display the modal window. Ager you log in the callback should be triggered containing your JWT token.